# Trying to Push Records from a Dataframe to a SQL Server Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, azure-sql-database, databricks

I am trying to find a way to push everything from a dataframe into a SQL Server table.  I did some Googling and came up with this.

```
Cluster.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://name_here.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=db_name") \
    .option("dbtable", "dbo.Cluster") \
    .option("user", "u_name") \
    .option("password", "p_wd") \
    .save()
```

My dataframe is named 'Cluster' and it is of type pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.  If the table exists in the DB, when I run the code above, I get this error message:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view &#39;dbo.Cluster&#39; already exists. SaveMode: ErrorIfExists.;
```

If I delete the table and run the code above I get this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can&#39;t get JDBC type for struct&lt;type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array&lt;int&gt;,values:array&lt;double&gt;&gt;
```

This should be do-able.  I've done this before in a Spark environment; that code worked perfectly fine.  Now, I am working in a Python environment (using Databricks), and I'm stuck on this one thing.

Just to come full-circle, I'm creating the dataframe this way:

```
df = spark.read \

.jdbc("jdbc:sqlserver://name_here.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=db_name", "dbo.table_name",
              properties={"user": "u_name", "password": "p_wd"})
```

Then...I do some analytics and the data...eventually I apply some ML algos to the data...and come up with two dataframes.

```
df1 = df1.select("*").toPandas()
df2 = df2("*").toPandas()
```

Now, I need to concatenate these two dataframes together.

```
Cluster = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Finally, I want to push this dataframe into a SQL Server table.  Everything works totally fine until I eventually try to put everything from the dataframe to the table.  That's the only issue I have here.

Answer (score 3):

You may try with a different SaveMode.Either Append to add data :

```
Cluster.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://name_here.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=db_name") \
    .option("dbtable", "dbo.Cluster") \
    .option("user", "u_name") \
    .option("password", "p_wd") \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

or Overwrite to replace the data :

```
Cluster.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://name_here.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=db_name") \
    .option("dbtable", "dbo.Cluster") \
    .option("user", "u_name") \
    .option("password", "p_wd") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save()
```

[Source](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html)

Comment: I tried both of these; neither worked.  On my first try, I I got a weird error.  Then, I was suing a Pandas DF.  I converted that to a pyspark.sql DF and re-ran your code.  Now, I'm getting another error.  Error message reads 'NameError: name 'SaveMove' is not defined'.  Any thoughts?  There has got to be a way to do this.

Comment: My bad, I fixed my code. Can you try it ?
It should be ```.mode("overwrite") ``` or ```.mode("append") ```

Comment: I just tried it again; I'm getting the same error as before: 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'

I converted it to 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' and I converted it to 'pyspark.sql.dataframe'.  Neither one worked.  :(

Comment: Can you share how you load the dataframe?

Comment: I just updated my original post with some more information.  Hopefully it helps.  Right now, I am a little lost with what's going on.  When I eyeball the code you posted, it seems, to me, like it should work just fine.  For some reason or another, it is NOT working for me.

Comment: I think I have it now. Your "Cluster" dataframe is a pandas dataframe, which explains why it doesn't have a 'write' attribute. You should first convert it to a Spark dataframe then write it. ```Cluster = spark.createDataFrame(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1))```
Hopefully, if this works, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Well, that totally makes sense.  When I do this: type(Cluster), I see: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.  But when I updated my code to reflect what you suggested, I got this: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can&#39;t get JDBC type for struct&lt;type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array&lt;int&gt;,values:array&lt;double&gt;&gt;

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out with this.  I'll try to think of some other solution, when I have more free time.  I have to switch to something else now.

Comment: I don't have a Pandas dataframe, still `.write.jdbc(url=connection_url, table="data_table").mode("overwrite").save()` fails to actually overwrite. pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException persists.